# Is there a use for the code in W 5-1 Shy Guy Jungle?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

In W5-1 "Shy Guy Jungle" there is an area of the level that features a trash heap.  Mario can pick up some scraps of trash that normally have miscellaneous memo-esque fluff written on them, except for one particular scrap.  This scrap has a code written on it, in the following format:

```
XD3R-B8HH-9ZR2-FL16
```

I've done a bit of looking around online, and have found that others have found the [exact same code](http://www.complex.com/video-games/2012/11/mysterious-code-paper-mario-sticker-star), or a [similar code](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997828-paper-mario-sticker-star/64605765) (only one character is different here, so I believe that this may actually be a typo) but nobody has, to date, found a use for the code.

It may simply be another piece of trash, because Mario reacts with a frown in a similar manner to the way he does with the remaining pieces of trash.  Does anyone have any additional insight to this?

Comment: No one really knows. People have tried it for nintendo subscriptions, DLC codes, etc. but nothing seems to work. I think the answer here is that there isn't one. The programmers just put in a code for fans to gawk over. Otherwise nintendo would have said at least something. No one will really have an answer for this unless they worked on the game itself.

Comment: Damn you, now I have to know ;_;

Comment: @Kevin It is truly the greatest mystery of our time.

Comment: @HyperAnthony nah that is the Secret of Monkey Island(tm).

Comment: [This thread](http://forum.blockland.us/index.php?topic=219065.0) is probably the most detailed one I found.  No answer yet though.

Answer (score 5):

This is an excellent question. I have been researching about this quite a bit.

There is no definitive answer to date. However, there are (as always) speculations. After doing some research I came upon groups of people that believed any of the following:

- It is a red herring.
- It is related to the sequel
- Related to a future dlc/demo
- It bears an unknown significance to the devs

I'm sorry if my answer is unsatisfactory; there is no real answer to your question as of yet.

Answer (score -2):

The code is found inside a garbage dump. It doesn't mean anything more than the other random messages and trash flyers found there.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Exchange. Do you have a reputable source that definitively states this as the case?  If not, I'm afraid it doesn't add anything to the question. In fact, exactly this same *speculation* was posited in the question body over a year ago.